# kubectl port-forward connection refused [ socat ]

Tags: portforwarding, kubectl, connection-refused, socat

I am running pyspark on one of the ports of kubernetes. I am trying to port forward to my local machine. I am getting this error while executing my python file.

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:7077 -> 7077
Forwarding from [::1]:7077 -> 7077
Handling connection for 7077
E0401 01:08:11.964798   20399 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 7077 -> 7077: error forwarding port 7077 to pod 68ced395bd081247d1ee6b431776ac2bd3fbfda4d516da156959b6271c2ad90c, uid : exit status 1: 2019/03/31 19:38:11 socat[1748104] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:7077, 16): Connection refused
```

this a few lines of my python file. I am getting error in the lines where conf is defined.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://localhost:7077").setAppName("Stand Alone Python Script")
```

I already tried installing `socat` on the kubernetes. I am using spark version 2.4.0 locally. I even tried exposing port 7077 in YAML file. Did not work out.

This is the YAML file used for deployment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-07T15:23:35Z
  generation: 16
  labels:
    chart: spark-0.2.1
    component: m3-zeppelin
    heritage: Tiller
    release: m3
  name: m3-zeppelin
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "55461362"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1beta1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/m3-zeppelin
  uid: f56e86fa-ca44-11e8-af6c-42010a8a00f2
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: m3-zeppelin
  serviceName: m3-zeppelin
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        chart: spark-0.2.1
        component: m3-zeppelin
        heritage: Tiller
        release: m3
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - bash
        - -c
        - wget -qO- https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.2.2/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
          | tar xz; mv spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7 spark; curl -sSLO https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar;
          mv gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar lib; ./bin/zeppelin.sh
        env:
        - name: SPARK_MASTER
          value: spark://m3-master:7077
        image: apache/zeppelin:0.8.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: m3-zeppelin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /zeppelin/conf
          name: m3-zeppelin-config
        - mountPath: /zeppelin/notebook
          name: m3-zeppelin-notebook
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: m3-zeppelin-config
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10G
      storageClassName: standard
    status:
      phase: Pending
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: m3-zeppelin-notebook
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10G
      storageClassName: standard
    status:
      phase: Pending
status:
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: m3-zeppelin-5779b84d99
  observedGeneration: 16
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updateRevision: m3-zeppelin-5779b84d99
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: Make sure to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of `localhost` or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google, Thanks for the reply. Can you help me with understanding how to listen on 0.0.0.0 ? Where to make these changes in code?

Comment: Try `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0`?

Comment: fair enough. thanks for the help :)

Comment: is this issue resolved? after sometime it got resolved automatically ?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue -- did this resolve your issue? why does it need to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost / 127.0.0.1? Anyways, I tried to change it and still get same error

Comment: For the problem was that I got the combination of `pod` name and `port` wrong. After fixing that the error was gone.

Comment: Some of the possible issues that is producing above error (`socat`: `connection refused`) could be either: **1.** application is not listening on the desired `port` **2.** `Port` that you are sending the requests to is incorrect (like sending to `port`: `81` instead of `port`:`80`).

Answer (score 4):

Focusing specifically on the error from the Kubernetes perspective it could be related to:

- Mismatch between the ports that request is sent to and the receiving end (for example sending a request to an `NGINX` instance on `port`: `1234`)
- `Pod` not listening on a desired `port`.

---

I've managed to reproduce this error with a Kubernetes cluster created with `kubespray`.

Assuming that you've run following steps:

- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl port-forward deployment/nginx 8080:80`

Everything should be correct and the `NGINX` welcome page should appear when running: `$ curl localhost:8080`.

If we made a change to the `port-forward` command like below (notice the `1234` port):

- `$ kubectl port-forward deployment/nginx 8080:1234`

You will get following error:

```sh
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 1234
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 1234
Handling connection for 8080
E0303 22:37:30.698827  625081 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 1234: error forwarding port 1234 to pod e535674b2c8fbf66252692b083f89e40f22e48b7a29dbb98495d8a15326cd4c4, uid : exit status 1: 2021/03/23 11:44:38 socat[674028] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:1234, 16): Connection refused
```

This would also work on a `Pod` that application haven't bound to the port and/or is not listening.

> A side note!
>
> You can simulate it by running an `Ubuntu` `Pod` where you try to curl its port 80. It will fail as nothing listens on its port. Try to `exec` into it and run `$ apt update && apt install -y nginx` and try to curl again (with `kubectl port-forward` configured). It will work and won't produce the error mentioned (`socat`).

---

Addressing the part of the question:

> I even tried exposing port 7077 in YAML file. Did not work out.

If you mean that you've included the `- containerPort: 8080`. This field is purely informational and does not carry any configuration to be made. You can read more about it here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Why do we need a port/containerPort in a Kuberntes deployment/container definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57198769/12257134)*

(which besides that I consider incorrect as you are using the port: `7077`)

---

As for the `$ kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0`. It's a way to expose your port-forward so that it would listen on all interfaces (on a host machine). It could allow for an access to your `port-forward` from `LAN`:

- `$ kubectl port-forward --help` (part):

```
  # Listen on port 8888 on localhost and selected IP, forwarding to 5000 in the pod
  kubectl port-forward --address localhost,10.19.21.23 pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Access application cluster: Port forward access to application cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use command:

```
kubectl get pods
```

to check whether your pods are running.
In my case, I start minikube without network connection, so I meet the same question when I use port-forward to trans pod's port to local mechine's port.