# Why do we need a port/containerPort in a Kuberntes deployment/container definition?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-container, kubernetes-networking

When I define e.g. a deployment in Kubernetes there is a section with a list of containers and each of them contains an array of ports, e.g.:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Now the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#container-v1-core) explicitly says it does not affect connectivity:

> List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives
> the system additional information about the network connections a
> container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port
> here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is
> listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be
> accessible from the network. Cannot be updated.

Now it seems it does not really affect anything and is only informational, but what does that really mean, where is that used?

I have found one use of that is that if port defines a name, it can be referenced from a service by that name.

Is that it or there are some other uses for this specification?

Comment: That's it. For documentation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As you quote the documentation,

> List of ports to expose from the container. Exposing a port here gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network. Cannot be updated.

the purpose of defining the `containerPorts` is purely for documentation. It is only used by other developers to understand the port that the container listens to. Kubernetes borrows this idea from docker which does the same with `EXPOSE` command as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Comment: it seems like containerPort isn’t purely informational if it has a name, and that name is used as the targetPort by a Service?

Answer (score 2):

(I know you mention services in your question but i just want to give some examples of what it looks like.)

If you define a service it can use the name of your container port to reference that port value.

For example, this is your pod definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: some-pod-name
  labels:
    app: some-label-name
spec:
  containers:
    - name: some-container-name
      image: some-container-image
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: some-image-http
```

Later when you define a service definition, instead of specifying a `targetPort` as a port number you can instead reference the containerPort name:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service-name
spec:
  selector:
    app: some-label-name
  ports:
  - port: 4080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: some-image-http #this will use port 8080 as defined in the pod.
```

See the documentation for this [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#field-spec-ports).

Answer (score 1):

One of the examples where this is being used by 3rd party products is istio and [kiali](https://kiali.io/docs/faq/graph/#why-are-there-many-unknown-nodes-in-the-graph)

> For a more definitive solution, you could have these endpoints (like /health or /metrics) exposed on a different port and server than your main application, and to not declare this port in your Pod’s container definition as containerPort. This way, the requests will be completely ignored by the Istio proxy, as mentioned in Istio documentation (at the bottom of that page).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Malathi's answer is wrong.

In a Kubernetes Deployment definition, the `containerPort` field is used to specify the port number on which the containers within the pods will listen for incoming network traffic. This field is an essential part of defining **how your application should be accessed** in the Kubernetes cluster.

For example:

1. **Service Discovery:** When you define a container's port using `containerPort`, you enable other pods and services within the cluster to discover and communicate with your pod. Kubernetes can route traffic to the correct pods **based on the specified port**.
2. **Load Balancing:** Kubernetes Services can load-balance traffic to pods **based** on the `containerPort`. Multiple pods can expose the same `containerPort`, allowing for easy load distribution.
3. **Health Checks:** Kubernetes can perform health checks on your application by sending requests to the container's port. If the application fails to respond as expected, Kubernetes can automatically restart the pod or take other actions, depending on your configuration.
4. **Ingress Controllers:** When configuring Ingress controllers or setting up Ingress resources to manage external access to your application, you often specify the target port (which corresponds to the `containerPort`) to route traffic correctly.
5. **Network Policies:** If you define network policies to control communication between pods, you may need to specify the `containerPort` to **allow** or **deny** traffic to specific ports.
6. **Service Type LoadBalancer:** When using a Service with type LoadBalancer, the `containerPort` determines which port the external load balancer should listen on and forward traffic to within the cluster.
7. **Exposing Multiple Ports:** If your container exposes multiple ports, you can specify each one separately using the `containerPort` field to differentiate between them and control their behavior individually.

Comment: I don't think `containerPort` is actually used for any of these cases.  Can you [edit] the answer, maybe focusing on one of these in particular and giving a specific example?