# is containerPort the port of the node application inside of the container?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

Node app:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

kubenetes deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nodejs-container
          image: your-nodejs-image:tag
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

Question:

1. can the `containerPort` be different from the port of the nodejs app, in this case 3000?

Comment: No. Use host port to bind it to a different one

Comment: Could you elaborate? By "no", do you mean that `containerPort` indeed cannot be different from 3000?

Comment: Well no because it’s what your node service is listening on

Comment: The [Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.29/#container-v1-core) spec`ports` does not change which ports are exposed by a Pod but is useful from a documentation perspective. Changing its value would **not** change the port used by (in this case) your Node app running in the container. The Node app itself with `server.listen(3000, {})` defines the port that will be used by the app, the container (`nodejs-container`), and the 3 (`replicas: 3`) Pods created by the Deployment (`nodejs-app`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `containerPort:` value should match the port number the application is using; in your example it should be exactly 3000 and nothing else.  At a mechanical level, Kubernetes does no checking on the value of `containerPort:`, and you technically can write in any port number you want there.

`containerPort:` actually does fairly little (also see [Why do we need a port/containerPort in a Kuberntes deployment/container definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197095/why-do-we-need-a-port-containerport-in-a-kuberntes-deployment-container-definiti)).  If you're using it in the case of assigning a name to a port to reference it from a Service, then it does need to match the port number that the process in the container is actually using.  Like other container port references (*e.g.*, the `docker run -p` option) the port number needs to match the application's port; changing the port number only at the container level will cause connectivity problems, it won't change where the application listens.